# Unexpected alpha values in DXT5 decompression

Tags: c#, .net, compression, textures

I am decompressing an image compressed with DXT5. According to the description each block of 16 bytes starts with 2 bytes alpha data. If i have a look at my file in a hex editor i find that 90% of the image have an alpha value of less than 0.04 (value in the file is < 10) which should not be the case.

If i render the image with OpenGL and let glCompressedTexImage do the work it looks ok. With my code the image is transparent as i would have expected from those small alpha values. The code i use to generate the alpha values looks like that:

```
byte alpha1 = reader.ReadByte();
byte alpha2 = reader.ReadByte();

uint[] alphaValues = new uint[8]
{
    alpha1,
    alpha2,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};

if (alpha1 > alpha2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        byte value = (byte)(((6.0f - i) * alpha1 + (1.0f + i) * alpha2) / 7.0f);
        alphaValues[i + 2] = value;
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        byte value = (byte)(((4.0f - i) * alpha1 + (1.0f + i) * alpha2) / 5.0f);
        alphaValues[i + 2] = value;
    }

    alphaValues[6] = 0;
    alphaValues[7] = 255;
}
```

alpha1 and alpha2 usually are the same (values are like 8 or 3 or 9, the maximum alpha value in the image however is 96).

The colors however are ok. If i render the image without alpha values it looks perfect. Enabling alpha -> transparent.

Comment: I need some clarification: "If i have a look at my file in a hex editor"-- does that mean the compressed DXT5 texture? Or the decompressed texture after being run through your code fragment above?

Comment: Its for the compressed data.

Comment: How did you compress the DXT5 textures? With your own tool? Someone else's tool? It sounds like the problem you're seeing is in the way the texture was compressed.